# A function symbol with more than one arity schema and type assigned to it in a signature

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra

I am studding many-sorted algebra. In this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397592903227#) (page 4), it is clearly said that in the signature $(S, \leq , \Sigma)$,  $\Sigma$ is a family $\Sigma=\{ \Sigma_{w,s}\}_{(w,s)\in S^*\times S}$ of (**not necessarily disjoint**) sets of operator symbols. Also we have a similar thing in [this one](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fsummary%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.22.3814&ei=TBBYVbm9CsGBygTwy4GADw&usg=AFQjCNGCnQKjIthvo2mO4Pi8tCsqQK_u2g&sig2=jfF1mgDgutOcwWFhMLlBog&bvm=bv.93564037,d.aWw) (page 6).

**My Questions:**

1)  Does this means that for one operator symbol, say $f$, we can assign more than one Arity  schema? (i.e., having one function symbols with different arities). In more detail, for example, I can have $f: A_1 \rightarrow B_1$, and also $f:A_1 \times A_2 \rightarrow B_1$. ( or I am missing something )

2) If answer to the question one is "yes", is this allowed in other areas of algebraic studies as well.

Comment: [Here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Signature_(Computer_Science)) it is mentioned that "F (i.e. $\Sigma$) may contain different function symbols designated in the same way and distinguished only by the function type". But the example that is provided (plus operation overloading) does not seem to be precise reflection of what it is said; since in overloading of plus operator we actually have one function symbol (i.e., + )  assigned to it two different types.

Comment: In other words, probably, it should have been  said instead "F (i.e. $\Sigma$) may contain a function symbol that is assigned to it different types; for example, overloading of plus operator is possible to achieve by assigning two different types to it, namely, $INT \times INT \rightarrow INT$ and  $FLOAT \times FLOAT \rightarrow FLOAT$."

Answer (score 1):

The answer to Question 1 is yes. The intention is that the same operator symbol can be used for (what I would call) several operators, of distinct arities.  This convention is quite unusual.  In principle, it would not cause problems if the same operation symbol $f$ is used with two (or more) arities that differ as to the inputs of $f$, because then one can infer the intended meaning of $f$ by looking at the arguments to which it is applied.  But things look bad (to me) if $f$ has two arities that involve the same input sorts but different output sorts.  Then, if $t_1,\dots,t_k$ have the appropriate sorts to serve as inputs of $f$, then $f(t_1,\dots,t_k)$ would have two meanings, of different sorts.

Comment: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.3814) (see page 6 footnote) actually refers to the problem you mentioned (i.e., $f(t_1,\dots, t_n)$ having two meanings). As I understand from the footnote I mentioned, any signature with this problem has an isomorphic signature without this problem.